# Override Button to draw text upside down

Tags: android, android-button, ondraw

How could I go about overriding the `Button` class to draw the text upside down? The formatting of other libraries I'm using screw up when the button itself it rotated, but I need the text flipped.

I'm not familiar with the `onDraw` method, and I'm not sure how I could make a subclass for this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rotation attribute in your button something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/test_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text button"
    android:rotation="180"/>
```

Or if you prefer using a custom button, you can create it something like this:

```
public class FlippedTextButton extends Button {
    public FlippedTextButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FlippedTextButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FlippedTextButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

        float y = this.getHeight() / 2.0f;
        float x = this.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        canvas.rotate(180, x, y);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it with:

```
<!-- Change to your class package name. -->
<com.example.flippedtext.FlippedTextButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Flipped text"/>
```

Here is the sample project on github: https://github.com/isnotmenow/FlippedText

Comment: Thanks so much, that's **exactly** what I needed! You rock!

Comment: Glad it helps you! ;)

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Hi, I need help with android studio, I need to do teamviewer. Are free right now? my problem is the apps suddenly shutdown by himself when I run test at the phone. Before this, it worked normally, the app can run smoothly. Can you check it for me?